# WordPress Bootstrap 5 CDN JS not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-5

I am developing a WP theme and like to use Bootstrap. For some reason I cannot get the Bootstrap 5 CDN JS to load in. The CSS V5 CDN has worked fine, just seems to be the JS thats not happy.

I have included a Bootstrap navbar, but when you click the .navbar-toggler nothing happens, no JS fires. It should open the navigation menu.

```
wp_register_script('bootstrap5', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', false, '5.1.3', true);
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap5');
```

I might add I have managed to get the JS to work but using a much older CDN which is super odd.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
```

Heres my nav code

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    $nav_id = 'site-navigation-fp';
    $nav_toggle_colour = 'navbar-dark';
} else {
    $nav_id = 'site-navigation';
    $nav_toggle_colour = 'navbar-light';
}
?>
<nav id="<?php echo $nav_id ?>" class="navbar navbar-expand-md <?php echo $nav_toggle_colour?>">
    <div class="container-lg navbar__wrapper">

        <?php if ( have_rows( 'site_logos', 'options' ) ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'site_logos', 'options' ) ) :
                the_row(); ?>

                <?php
                $primary_logo = get_sub_field( 'primary_logo', 'options' );
                if ( $primary_logo && is_front_page() ) : ?>
                    <figure class="navbar__logo">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $primary_logo['url'] ); ?>"
                             alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $primary_logo['alt'] ); ?>"/>
                    </figure>
                <?php else: ?>

                    <?php
                    $secondary_logo = get_sub_field( 'secondary_logo', 'options' );
                    if ( $secondary_logo ) : ?>
                        <figure class="navbar__logo">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $secondary_logo['url'] ); ?>"
                                 alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $secondary_logo['alt'] ); ?>"/>
                        </figure>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler"
                aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="my-1 mx-2 close">X</span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            </span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                            'theme_location'       => 'menu-1',
                            'menu_id'              => 'primary-menu',
                            'container_class'      => 'ms-auto ',
                            'menu_class'           => 'navbar-nav navbar-nav-scroll',
                            'container_aria_label' => 'primary navigation'
                    )
            );
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check the browser console for error message. Anything there?

Comment: Console is clear of any errors or warnings